# raspar comentários de portal de notícia

Tags: python

sou entusiasta de programação. estou tentando fazer raspagem de comentários de um portal de notícia para fazer uma tag cloud.

Estou tentando fazer isso usando o Beautiful Soap mas tenho obtido um retorno None. Segue o código que estou usando. Alguma dica? Meu conhecimento é bem amador, sou curioso, não estoudo então talvez tenha alguma coisa de estrutura de site aí que eu não conheça e devia conhecer. Consegui raspar o texto mas não os comentários. Obrigado

```
 import urllib.request
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 coments = 'https://esporte.uol.com.br/futebol/campeonatos/copa-do- 
 brasil/ultimas-noticias/2019/02/06/santos-toma-susto-mas-faz-7-a-1-no-altos-e-avanca-na-copa-do-brasil.htm'
 page = urllib.request.urlopen(coments)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
 v = soup.find("div", {"id": "comentarios"})
 print(v)
 [None]
```

Answer (score 3):

Com esse seu código você não conseguiria captar nenhum comentário porque os comentários estão em uma tag `<p class="comment-text ng-binding ng-scope" [...]>`. Logo, sua linda do `soup.find` deveria ser:

```
v = soup.find_all("p", class_="comment-text ng-binding ng-scope"})
```

Olha que aqui eu uso `find_all()` pra encontrar todos os comentários e não só o primeiro, o que aconteceria se eu usasse o `find()`. E eu uso também o atributo `class_` e não `class`; isso porque no Python a palavra `class` é reservada, daí para usar o Beautiful Soup temos que digitar `class_`, com um underline no final.

No entanto, os comentários do UOL são protegidos contra web scraping. Logo, como você está começando, recomendo estudar um pouco de scraping com algo mais simples, entender como funcionam as tags e como achar o conteúdo que você precisa nelas.

Comment: A propósito, recomendo usar a biblioteca `requests` ou a `mechanicalsoup` no lugar na `urllib.request` pra fazer scraping. A `mechanicalsoup` é bem mais fácil de usar, mas você não vai conseguir fazer scraping em conteúdo de páginas baseadas em JavaScript. Documentação da [Mechanical Soup](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html).

Comment: entendi. que pena. Muito obrigado. é que eu li que o melhor jeito de aprender os conceitos de programação é escolhendo algo que gostaria de fazer e eu gosto muito dessa parte analítica de sentimentos e acho os portais de notícia o melhor lugar pra uma amostragem mais genuína da reação das pessoas.